# How to install SCIP into Spyder (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, scip

Can someone please tell me how to install SCIP module into Spyder (Python 3.6). This is linked to anaconda by the way. I have been trying to get this module into this python 3.6 for last two days, and I am not getting anywhere. It is frustrating.

I need it solve a mixed integer programming problem.

Honestly, I do not care what programming language we use as long as I can solve my MIP problem. However, it will best if SCIP gets installed into Spyder (Python 3.6) because I am familiar with the language.

Please tell me the quickest and easiest way to do this. I also just downloaded and installed the stand-alone python 3.6. I would really appreciate, if someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

I am trying to run the following code:

```
from zibopt import scip
solver = scip.solver()

# All variables have default lower bounds of 0
x1 = solver.variable(scip.INTEGER)
x2 = solver.variable(scip.INTEGER)
x3 = solver.variable(scip.INTEGER)

# x1 has an upper bound of 2
solver += x1 <= 2

# Add a constraint such that:  x1 + x2 + 3*x3 <= 3
solver += x1 + x2 + 3*x3 <= 3

# The objective function is: z = x1 + x2 + 2*x3
solution = solver.maximize(objective=x1 + x2 + 2*x3)

# Print the optimal solution if it is feasible.
if solution:
    print('z  =', solution.objective)
    print('x1 =', solution[x1])
    print('x3 =', solution[x2])
    print('x2 =', solution[x3])
else:
    print('invalid problem')
```

Error I am getting:

```
from zibopt import scip

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zibopt'
```

I have already placed scip folder into site-packages folder in the C: drive, and hoped that it would work. I have few other things, but I don't remember what they were.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136688/discussion-on-question-by-bob-how-to-install-scip-into-spyder-python-3-6).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use SCIP in Python you should use this interface: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt

I don't even know how you found the old zibopt package without stumbling over PySCIPOpt.

And by the way, if you only want to solve a mixed integer program, you can simply download a binary/executable of [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/#download) for the platform of your choice. You then need to model your problem in some way, e.g. using [ZIMPL](http://zimpl.zib.de/) or simply as a plain `.lp` file (see [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/lp_format.html) for a format description).

Comment: I am glad you are helping me here because I see you are the one who was part of the PySCIPOpt. I think you would be the best person to help me resolve. Before anything, I want to know where I can download Python to have SCIP or ZIMPL into it. I have Spyder (Python 3.6), but I don't think anyone is familiar with that. That's what I want to use, but if I can't then that's okay. But, then what do I use? I am ready to do this from scratch if you can help me. I am clueless about using installing all these modules and libraries. I would appreciate if you could guide me. Thanks!

Comment: All these folders look the same to me. I have downloaded PySCIPOpt, PuLP, SCIP, Gurobi, ZIMPL. What do I do after extracting them is my question. I just want easy instructions to follow. I am not an expert in this at all. This is my first time doing it. Yes, I only want to solve a MIP problem.

Comment: You need to make yourself more familiar with the tools you want to use. Python is a programming language, Spyder is an IDE for Python and SCIP, ZIMPL and Gurobi are C tools for modeling and solving (among others) mixed integer programs. As I said above, there is no need to build or install any of these tools. Simply download the binaries from the link I mentioned above and run them. Oh, and please don't forget to mark my answer 'accepted' to close this thread.

Comment: "Simply download the binaries from the link I mentioned above and run them." How do I run them? And are you saying that if I run this, it will work in Spyder or not?

Comment: Seriously? You double click the executable. And no, this won't do anything regarding Spyder. And please try a bit harder first before asking questions.

Comment: What is this ?   The SCIP Python interface uses the shared library of the SCIP Optimization Suite.
Therefore you have to run

    make SHARED=true scipoptlib

from the root of the SCIP Optimization directory. This will result in the creation
of the directory "<path_to_scipopt/lib>" and the shared library "libscipopt.so". How do I even do that? And where?

Answer (score -1):

You could simply download & install Gusek (https://sourceforge.net/projects/gusek/) and model the problem in MathProg (cut and paste the following text in gusek IDE, save & run):

```
/*# All variables have default lower bounds of 0*/
var x1 integer, >=0;
var x2 integer, >=0;
var x3 integer, >=0;

/*# x1 has an upper bound of 2*/
s.t. upx1: x1 <= 2;

/*# Add a constraint such that:  x1 + x2 + 3*x3 <= 3*/

s.t. c1: x1 + x2 + 3*x3 <= 3;


/*# The objective function is: z = x1 + x2 + 2*x3*/

maximize FunObj:x1 + x2 + 2*x3;


solve;

end;
```

You can also use gusek (Ctrl-2 in gusek IDE) to generate an *.lp (CPLEX format) and solve it with standalone SCIP.